# Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $ . How can i fix this

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I'm trying to resolve the malformed JSON issue while dealing with the JSON object. It dumps the error on my project's console stating that `Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $`. How can I fix this? 
**Send Remote Message**

```
private fun sendRemoteMessage(body: sender) {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://fcm.googleapis.cm/fcm/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java).sendRemoteMessage(body).enqueue( object :Callback<String> {

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
            if (response.code() == 200 && response.isSuccessful){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Message sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**API Service**

```
@Headers({
       "Content-Type:application/json",
"Authorization:key=myServerKey"
    })
    @POST("send")
    Call<String> sendRemoteMessage(@Body sender body);
```

**Handling Data**

```
private fun initiateMeeting(meetingType: String, receiverToken: String) {
    val data = user()
    data.name = preferenceManager.getString(Constants().keyUserName).toString()
    data.profilePic = preferenceManager.getString((Constants().keyProfile)).toString()
    data.email = preferenceManager.getString(Constants().keyEmail).toString()
    data.token = preferenceManager.getString(Constants().keyRemoteMsgSenderToken).toString()

    val sender = sender(data, receiverToken)

    sendRemoteMessage(sender)
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, sender.data.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

**Data Sender**

```
class sender(var data: data, var to: String)
```

**Data Class**

```
class user: Serializable {
    var name = ""
    var profilePic = ""
    var token: String = ""
    var email = ""
}
```

Comment: It might be the headers you're sending. There should always be a space between the `:` colon and the content of the header. It might get wrongly interpreted as the request content otherwise. If it isn't that, also tell us where exactly this error happens including the stack trace.

Comment: But I put space after colon : still facing the same issue

Comment: You still need to provide more info. Show us the stack trace, what are you parsing, do you have the response data, is it your own api?